# Selenium Web driver - Locate by Class name

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to click on the search auto complete `BUTTON` in a webmail application.

```
<button class="_n_r ms-bg-color-themeLight-hover o365button _n_s ms-bg-color-themeLighter ms-font-color-neutralPrimary ms-border-color-themePrimary" type="button" autoid="_n_4" aria-label="Activate Search Textbox">
<span class="_n_u owaimg ms-Icon--search ms-icon-font-size-20 ms-fcl-ts-b"/>
<span class="_n_t ms-font-weight-semilight ms-font-color-neutralPrimary">Search Mail and People</span>
```

When clicking the `BUTTON`, we get this `INPUT`

```
<input class="_is_x ms-font-weight-semibold ms-font-color-neutralPrimary ms-bg-color-themeLight ms-bg-color-themeLight-hover allowTextSelection textbox ms-font-s ms-fwt-sl ms-fcl-np ms-bcl-nta ms-bcl-nsa-h hideClearButton" autoid="_is_3" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-label="Search mail and people, type your search term then press enter to search."/>
```

I'm getting the following error while trying to use the class name from the input.

> "The given selector _n_r ms-bg-color-themeLight-hover o365button _n_sms-bg-color-themeLighter ms-border-color-themeLighter is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted"

We tried to use selenium IDE to fetch the value, but we are getting only the xpath. Is there any way to locate autocomplete search field with out using the xpath?

Answer (score 0):

That's a LOT of classes on that `INPUT`. :) I would use a different attribute. I would start with one of these and see which one works for you. You didn't specify the language you are using so here's some code in Java.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[autoid='_is_3']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[aria-label='Search mail and people, type your search term then press enter to search.']"));
```

Quick note since you were asking about classes. You can go the classes route and use CSS Selectors to find them. A simple example.

```
<button class="one two">
```

You can find the `BUTTON` above using

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.one.two"));
```

A period (.) indicates a CSS class so you would need a period before each class name. You don't necessarily need to include *all* the classes, only enough to make the element unique so you can locate it.

[CSS Selectors reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS Selectors tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)